# How to Moq an update method in controller

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I am trying to mock a method that updates an entry into the database using EF.

```
class MyController
{
     private readonly IEmployeeRepository;
     private readonly IProjectRepository;

     MyController(IEmployeeRepository employeeRepository,IProjectRepository projectRepository)
     {
          _employeeRepository=employeeRepository;
          _projectRepository=projectRepository;
     }

     public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ExtendEmployeeContract(int employeeId, int projectId)
     {
            var projectModel=_projectRepository.GetProjectDetails(projectId);
            int result=-1;
            if(projectMode !=null)
            {
                bool isprojectactive=projectMode.IsActive;

                // Some made-up function that is setting the IsContractActive value to true/false
                result=_employeeRepository.ExtendContract
                            (new EmployeeModel(){Id = employeeId,IsContractActive = isprojectactive};);

            }

            return Ok(new ResponseModel(){Data=result});
     }
}

[TestClass]
class MyControllerTestClass
{
   private Mock<IEmployeeRepository> _mockedEmployeeRepository;
   private Mock<IProjectRepository> _mockedProjectRepository;
   ProjectModel _projectModel;
   EmployeeModel _empModel;

   [TestInitialize]
   public void TestInitialize()
   {
      _mockedEmployeeRepository = new Mock<IEmployeeRepository>();
     _mockedProjectRepository = new Mock<IProjectRepository>();
     _projectModel = new ProjectModel()
     {
            Id = 5678,
            Name = "testProject",
            IsActive=true;
     };

     _empModel = new EmployeeModel()
     {
            Id = 123,
            IsContractActive = false
     };
   }

   [TestMethod]
   public async Task ExtendEmployeeContract_ShouldUpdateAndExtend_EmployeeContract()
   {
       // Arrange
         _mockedProjectRepository.Setup(x=>x.GetProjectDetails(5678)).Returns(_projectModel);
         _mockedEmployeeRepository.Setup(x=>x.ExtendContract(_empModel)).Returns(1);

       // Act
        var mycontroller=new MyController(_mockedEmployeeRepository.object,_mockedProjectRepository.object);
        var actionResult = await mycontroller.ExtendEmployeeContract(123,5678) as OkNegotiatedContentResult<ResponseModel>;

       // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(1,Convert.ToInt(actionResult.Content.Data.ToString());
   }
}
```

I am trying to mock this controller in my test class . I can successfully mock GetProjectDetails method but I cant mock `ExtendContract`. I debugged the `ExtendEmployeeContract` method and found that `_employeeRepository.ExtendContract` always returns 0

Comment: Just to be clear, you are mocking the repository used by the controller. You are testing the controller. 

ExtendContract is always returning 0 because your setup of the mocked method is checking for an exact match of _empModel, which it is not finding, and therefore it is returning the default value. You should add some expression to the setup call to either accept any EmployeeModel or an EmployeeModel whose ID matches what was given in the controller arguments.

Comment: What you are trying to do is not actually test the functionality of the controller but test the functionality of the repository. As the repository is mocked you cannot do that. What you can test is that the repository is called and the value returned by the mock is returned by the controller. To test the functionality of the repository requires a real repository - not a mock.

Comment: @EricMagers Sorry I am new to Moq and Unittesting. How do I do that?

Comment: @Rohit this gives some basic examples on how to use Linq expressions for this https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#matching-arguments

Answer (score -1):

Your fake setup is wrong. Even though you are passing your EmployeeModel

```
_mockedEmployeeRepository.Setup(x=>x.ExtendContract(_empModel)).Returns(1);
```

In your controller code you are creating `new` Employee model, which is different from what you pass in test

```
 result=_employeeRepository.ExtendContract
                        (new EmployeeModel(){Id = employeeId,IsContractActive = isprojectactive};);
```

Your fake setup should look like:

```
_mockedEmployeeRepository.Setup(x=>x.ExtendContract(It.IsAny<EmployeeModel>())).Returns(1);
```